# Underline for entire line when using span and position:absolute

Tags: html, css

Below is the html I am using to display some content. I have learnt that an underline wouldn't be visible in hyperlinks when using `"position:absolute"`, which is why I have added the style `text-decoration: underline;` , for the span elements.

However, I am getting underlines where the span element displays a text. I would link to have a underline the entire line containing all the text's of span.

Please check the snippet and output here . However, I need a underline on entire line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
a {
    text-decoration: underline; }
</style>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" >
<div class="sans-serif" >
<font style="font-weight:normal; font-size:12.00pt; font-style:normal; ">
<span style="position:absolute; top:94px; left:42px;text-decoration: underline;  ">Text2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; top:94px; left:213px;text-decoration: underline; ">Text3</span>
<span style="position:absolute; top:94px; left:418px;text-decoration: underline; ">Text4</span>
</font>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I would need the below output, but using span elements as shown above using position:absolute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
a {
    text-decoration: underline; }
</style>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" >
<div class="sans-serif" >
<font style="font-weight:normal; font-size:12.00pt; font-style:normal; ">
Text 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text 3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text4
</font>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use border-bottom rather than text-decoration and give width 100% or pixel to span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have restuctured you HTML, no need to use font tags and unnecessary `<div>`s inside your HTML. Besides, it is best practice to make all of your style inside the `<style>` tag and not inline.

I have made the `<a>` display as table and made all the spans display as table-cell in order to apply a full border beneath them, and upon the hover of the `<a>` the border is removed.

I have also created specific classes for the first and last spans in order to align them left and right in their cells. Other cells will be aligned center.

Working snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

#wrapper
{
   padding-top:5%;
    padding-left:10%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:table;
   
    width:50%;
     font-weight:normal; 
    font-size:12.00pt; 
     font-style:normal; 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

a span {
     white-space:nowrap; 
     display:table-cell; 
     border-bottom: solid 1px #0000EE; 
     width:30%;
     text-align:center;
  }

a:hover span {
   border-bottom: none; 
}

.first
{
   text-align:left;
 }

.last
{
   text-align:right;
 }

</style>
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" >
     <span class="first" >Text2</span>
     <span>Text3</span>
     <span class="last"  >Text4</span>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ent6vxp2/)**

HTML:

```
<p class="sans-serif"> 
<a href="#">
<span>Text2</span>
<span >Text3</span>
<span >Text4</span>    
</a>    
</p>
```

CSS:

```
 a {
     clear:both;
     position:relative;
     top:94px;
     border-bottom:1px solid red;
     left:42px;
     text-decoration:none;
     width:100%;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 a span {
     clear:both;
     border-bottom:1px solid red;
     margin-left:95px;
 }
 a span:first-child {
     clear:both;
     border-bottom:1px solid red;
     margin-left:0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to can add the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes after the span tag to add the underline

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
a {
    text-decoration: underline; }

    span:nth-child(2):before{
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     width: 500%;
     right: 50%;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #000;
  bottom: 2px;
    }

    span:nth-child(2):after{
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     width: 500%;
     left: 50%;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #000;
  bottom: 2px;
  }

 </style>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" >
<div class="sans-serif" >
<font style="font-weight:normal; font-size:12.00pt; font-style:normal; ">
<span style="position:absolute; top:94px; left:42px;text-decoration: underline; ">Text2</span>
<span style="position:absolute; top:94px; left:213px;text-decoration: underline; ">Text3</span>
<span style="position:absolute; top:94px; left:418px;text-decoration: underline; ">Text4</span>
</font>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
a {
     position:absolute;
     border-bottom:1px solid red;
     text-decoration:none;     
}
a span {  
     margin-left:100px;
}
a span:first-child{
     margin:0px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<p class="sans-serif"> 
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" >
<span>Text2</span>
<span >Text3</span>
<span >Text4</span>    
</a>    
</p>
```